# add prefix to id in template if flag is set in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

My database was something like this :

```
| id | customer_account | -few more fields - | is_renewed |
| 25 |    asd111        | - some values -    |     0      |
| 26 |    asd222        | - some values -    |     1      |
| 27 |    asd333        | - some values -    |     1      |
| 28 |    asd444        | - some values -    |     0      |
```

in my models, I have :

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    customer_account = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    --few more fields--
    is_renewed = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def use_updated_id(self):
        if self.is_renewed:
            new_id = str("R") + str(self.id)
        else:
            new_id = self.id
        return new_id
```

in my template, I have :

```
{% for policy in policy_list % }
<p> Policy Number : {{policy.id}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

which gives me output as

```
Policy Number : 25
Policy Number : 26
Policy Number : 27
Policy Number : 28
```

I understand that I can define a method in model and use that instead of id as below to meet my requirement

```
{% for policy in policy_list % }
<p> Policy Number : {{policy.use_updated_id}} </p>
{% endfor %}



Policy Number : 25
Policy Number : R26
Policy Number : R27
Policy Number : 28
```

My only challenge is that if use model method as above, i will have to replace updated multiple templates.

I'm looking for a better solution where in i only have to make changes in models file instead of updating multiple templates to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

So you have `{{ policy.id }}` in multiple templates and want to change its behavior by making changes to `models.py`?

AFAIK you cannot achieve that, since you haven't correctly encapsulated the display beforehand. That's a pain, but you'll have to change it everywhere, since you're accessing a particular attribute on your models. Adding your `use_updated_id` is a great idea, since it encapsulates the display logic in one function and, in the future, if you need to change the display all you have to do is to change your new function.

So go on, make those hundreds of file edits but be sure that now you've made a great progress and facilitated your project maintainability.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what else could have been done to achieve my desired output. 

I understand that another way of doing it could have been through custom model manager, but again, that would also require me to go through multiple templates to update the manager name in the queries.